# Is this iOS app issue when status bar is sticked to the right side in portrait?

Tags: ios

**My steps:**

**1)** Launch the app (the app works in portrait mode only)

**2)** Rotate the device to landscape during changing activity

*Now the device is in landscape. The activity is changed and still in portrait mode (this is okay). But the iOS status bar becomes sticked to the right side.*

**3)** Rotate the device to portrait

*The iOS status bar is still sticked to the right side.*

**4)** Tap Home button (in portrait)

*Now the app is minimized and the iOS status bar becomes sticked to the top side.*

**5)** Maximize the app again (in portrait)

*The iOS status bar becomes again sticked to the right side.*

**Is this issue of iOS or issue of the app?**

Comment: are you talking about a specific app or in general? what do you mean by the status bar sticked to the right?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ 1) this is specific app. I'm testing it. 2) The normal position of the status bar in portrait mode is on the screen top. But I see the status bar in portrait mode on the screen right (looks like in landscape).

Comment: Here is screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R4CJkwmmB9DT9tXkL2pLMAVw7gqh5WP2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @milan-nosáľ, what do you think?

Comment: I have never seen (or at least I dont remember it) such a behavior..

Comment: More details about step 2..

Comment: The app uploads/downloads videos, and playback them. It works only in portrait. I upload own video and open the video screen after uploading. After that I tap "delete video" and turn into landscape when the video is deleting and the activity is changed to the previous with my videos list.
Maybe you have any ideas about this? Unfortunately, I don't develop for iOS, and don't know how iOS apps work on back-end.